# What is the proper articles for these sentences ?

Tags: articles

I have got a sentence.

Il faut acheter de l'eau et de café.

My question is why `l'eau` has gotten an articles after de but café did not receive any and if it is possible to add the article to it too.

Comment: Are you it is not a typo? I'd say Il faut acheter de l'eau et du café. (De+le contract into du).

Comment: I actually saw it on the Internet. This might be case. Appreciated your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No native speaker but I'd say that it is most possibly a typo.

> Il faut acheter **de l**'eau et **du**[1] café.

[1] De+le contract into du (search for article partitif).

Comment: I accepted your answer my good sir.